# Wordpress + .htaccess redirect based on domain

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have 2 servers on digital ocean (Love them!), a varnish cache, and a wordpress backend. 
`http://domain.com` is set to the varnish cache. `server1.domain.com` is set to the second server as a backend, so I can have direct access without hitting the cache.

I've set wordpress to use both domains any `$_SERVER['hostname']`. Loading `Server1.domain.com` works fine, all links go to `server1.domain.com`, but many files and stylesheets still say `domain.com`

It it possible to use a rewrite condition to look at the hostname, and if its `server1.domain.com`, and if so, redirect all `domain.com` to `server1.domain.com`?

I've seen redirects for `www` to `domain.com`, but I'm only looking to do this if the hostname is `server1.domain.com`